# Cannot call method from view

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I cannot call the method from the controller
This is the view

```
<% songartist = change_artist(songartist) %>
<%= @artistnum  %></b> total songs.
```

This is my controller

```
 def mylist_artist
    @songs = current_user.songs.all
    @songartists = @songs.pluck(:artist).uniq

    def change_artist(link)

        require 'uri' 
        require 'open-uri' 
        require 'nokogiri' 

        @changed = URI::encode(params[:link]) 
        linkurl = "https://www.ufret.jp/artist.php?data="+@changed 
        doc = Nokogiri::HTML(open(linkurl)) 
        @artistnum = doc.xpath(" //a [@class= 'list-group-item list-group-item-action normal-chord']/strong").children.count
        return @artistnum 
    end 
end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm going to focus only on the problem stated in the question *"Cannot call method from view"*;

You can't invoke that method because in the context you're (the view), that method is inaccessible without initializing the controller where it's defined. You can achieve that as follows:

```
<%= songartist = SomeController.new.mylist_artist('foo') %>
```

By previously updating the `mylist_artist` method by adding an argument:

```
def mylist_artist(link)
  ...
end
```

But you should never do that because we don't usually write nested methods in Ruby that way. As you can see, the only thing it returns is the name of the `change_artist` as a symbol, which happens to be the return value of that method.

If you plan to use `change_artist` in the View layer, you should move it to a helper. Since that's the norm and Rails allows you to invoke them without having to do much.

Just add a new file to your `app/helpers/` directory, and move the method there:

```
# app/helpers/some_helper.rb
module SomeHelper
  def change_artist(link)
    ...
  end
end
```

Now in your view you can simply do:

```
<% songartist = change_artist('foo') %>
```

Comment: It actually worked! Thank you so much for your help. Right now, I'm making my first rials app. There are millions of things to figure out, but with the help of you guys make it possible for me to get closer to finishing my first app.

Answer (score 1):

This is not supposed to work. If you really want to call such a method in your views, you'll have to put it into a `app/helpers/foo_helper.rb`.

Answer (score 1):

You're defining a method inside another method...

Anyway if you want to call a method from the view you should define it in a helper class not in the controller.